# Cannot delete node in bootstrap gtreetable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have implemented bootstrap gtreetable in my project. Everything works fine but i have a problem with deleting the node. I have all bootstrap-gtreetable.js and bootstrap-gtreetable.min.js in place. Create and Update works file, but only delete is not working neither it throws any error in console. My code is as follows.
My jquery code for initializing gtreetable is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#gtreetable').gtreetable({
        'source': function (id) {
            return {
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'GetCategories',
                data: { 'id': id },
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.status + ': ' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        "onSave": function (oNode) {
           if( oNode.getName().length>0)
            return {
                type: 'POST',
                url: !oNode.isSaved() ? 'CreateCategory' : '/Category/UpdateCategory/?id=' + oNode.getId(),
                data: {
                    parent: oNode.getParent(),
                    name: oNode.getName(),
                    position: oNode.getInsertPosition(),
                    related: oNode.getRelatedNodeId()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.status + ': ' + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            };

           window.location.refresh();
        },
        "onDelete": function (oNode) {
            return {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Category/DeleteCategory/?id=' + oNode.getId(),
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.status+': '+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            };
        },
        "selectLimit": 0,
        "showExpandIconOnEmpty": false,
        "language": "en-US",
        "manyroots": false,
        "draggable": false,
        "inputWidth": "300px",
        'types': {
            'folder': 'glyphicon glyphicon-tasks',
            'default': 'glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard'
        },
        "defaultActions": [
            {
                name: 'Create Category',
                event: function (oNode, oManager) {
                    oNode.add('lastChild', 'default');
                }
            },
            {
                divider: true
            },
            {
                name: 'Update',
                event: function (oNode, oManager) {
                    oNode.makeEditable();
                }
            },
             {
                 divider: true
             },
            {
                name: 'Delete',
                event: function (oNode,oManager) {
                    oNode.onDelete;
                }
            },
            {
                divider: true
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

My server side code to delet node is as follow:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public virtual JsonResult DeleteCategory(int id)
        {

            var category = _categoryService.DeleteCategory(id);

            return Json(category, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code in to the question. Images of code are useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue i need to modify the gtreetable.js
The original code was like this:

```
   languages: {
        'en-US': {
            save: 'Save',
            cancel: 'Cancel',
            action: 'Action',
            actions: {
                createBefore: 'Create before',
                createAfter: 'Create after',
                createFirstChild: 'Create first child',
                createLastChild: 'Create last child',
                update: 'Update',
                'delete': 'Delete'
            },
            messages: {
                onDelete: 'Are you sure?',
                onNewRootNotAllowed: 'Adding the now node as root is not allowed.',
                onMoveInDescendant: 'The target node should not be descendant.',
                onMoveAsRoot: 'The target node should not be root.'
            }                
        }
    },
```

I have change 'delete' in action property to remove and it works fine